# getDay() return different value to different browsers/computers

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, cross-browser, operating-system

I have this code to find the value of weekday of 2012-01-24 (which should be Tuesday):

============

```
var myDay=new Date();

myDay.setUTCFullYear(2012, 0, 24);

document.write(myDay.getDay());
```

============

However, different browser/computer shows me different value, some gives 1, some gives 2.

Any clue to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For `myDay = new Date();`, use [`myDay.getUTCDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) to get one value for each browser and country. The ordinary [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) method returns a locale-specific value.

Comment: Indeed.  The date you created is at midnight UTC.  So depending on which timezone you're in it could be the previous day or the next day in your timezone at midnight UTC.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However, all the browsers/computers tested are in US Easter time zone.

Comment: Sorry.  Sent the post by accident.  All browsers/computers tested are in the same time zone.  The only difference is the versions of Windows and browsers.  Anyway, if I am trying to find the current day/time, I could understand the day would be different.  However, what I am trying to find is the weekday of a specific date.  Regardless of time zone, any specific date should have the same weekday, no?  I am confused.  @_@

Comment: Thanks to Rob and Boris.  I see what you mean.  Maybe the time zone of some computers were not properly set although they all show correct current local date and time.